# concatenate strings of rows according to column

Tags: mysql

I hava table

```
MsgID    Msg              value
ms001    I am here.       ----
ms001    Wher are you     dsdad
ms002    who r u          gfsdfdf
ms002    where is this    dadad
ms002    I am goin        adadad
```

Is this possible to get result like this by MySQL query

```
ms001    I am here. Wher are you
ms002    who r u wher is this I am goin
```

Comment: You will need to read through [Group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Read about group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

```
SELECT MsgID , GROUP_CONCAT(Msg SEPARATOR ' ') AS Msg
FROM table1
GROUP BY MsgID;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2760f/1)**